# It is possible with CSS to show a visual indicator like an arrow to inform there is a sub menu?

Tags: css

There´s my code below, now I´m trying to know if there is some CSS property to inform users that there is a sub menu in my `<li>test</li>`. Is it possible?

```html
<section id="menu-container">

    <nav id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="pagina.html">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li>test
               <ul>
                   <li><a href="#">item a</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">item b</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">item c</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">item d</a></li>
              </ul>
           </li>
        </ul>

    </nav>   

</section>
```

CSS:

```css
#menu {width:960px; height:auto; margin:0 auto 0 auto;}
#menu ul {list-style-type:none;}
#menu ul li {float:left; height:46px;line-height:46px;  font-weight:300;}
#menu ul li a {text-decoration:none;color:#ccc;  display:block; margin-right:5px; height:46px; line-height:46px; padding:0 5px 0 5px;font-size:20px; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no CSS property that detect a child element.

However it's simple enough to do with JQuery...in fact there are an number of ways with JQ

Here's one.

**JQuery**

```
(function($) {
  $("nav > ul").addClass("top-level");
  $(".top-level li:has(ul)").addClass("parent");
})(jQuery)
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/55e2c755a20da404090951a63584f4d0)

Comment: @Paulie_D I used your code as a base and solved it without JS. Thanks for your example provided. I tweaked it a bit to make it work...

Answer (score 2):

Just for the record it is possible without JS:

What I did is to specify a styling for child `ul`-elements nested within an `li`.
The sub-ul is not `visibility:hidden` as in the previous example, the child elements are.

So here you go:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ufGdm

@Paulie_D I used your code as basic and just changed some parts.

Comment: Nice job! Have an up-vote. IMHO, this is the correct answer since we're talking about styling (and not behavior).